# SSRS query date format and parameter date formats differ?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, date, reporting-services, bids

**BIDS/Visual studio 2005**

Hi, I've had a look through SO Questions and cannot find an answer. I'm sure there must be one there somewhere.

This looks like a simple problem, but I've tried a number of variations but cannot find a solution!

Simple Dataset : "DateRange" to give me a dd/mm/yyyy hr:mn:ss format such as

```
FromDate                 ToDate
2016-04-24 00:00:00.000 2016-04-25 23:59:59.997

select (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) AS FLOAT) ) AS DATETIME)) AS 'FromDate',
DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, getdate()), 0)) as 'ToDate'
```

I then use FromDate and ToDate as parameters in the report as default values. However, these are then displayed in in the **parameter fields** as **"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mn:ss"** format!

My control panel settings are UK English. This works in the Visual Studio "Preview" but falls over on deploy as the date is not recognised! Any suggestions??

Comment: My understanding is that the date format in the parameter panel is fixed in that awful american format and there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Each report has its own localization settings. In the Properties panel for the report you will see a `Language` property in the Localization section. You can set this to `en-GB` which should solve your problem. However, I generally set it to `=User!Language` to use the regional settings of the user.

**Edit**

Since that isn't working, let's convert to military date format (all elements in descending order of magnitude - year, month, day, hour, etc) as a string and let the application convert it back to a date. This format is the most robust way of passing dates around to avoid regional issues:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)), 121) AS 'FromDate',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, getdate()), 0)), 121) as 'ToDate'
```

Comment: Thanks @ChisLatta. I've already tried setting the Language to English but this made no difference. I've also tried your suggestion of `=User!Language` but no luck there either!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could get to work in the time available was to set the SSRS parameter as a string and convert the date to a string as follows:

```
select distinct left(convert(varchar, (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadd(d,-1,mydate)   AS FLOAT) ) AS DATETIME)),120),30) as FromDate,
left(convert(varchar, DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, mydate), 0)),120),30) as ToDate
from mydb
order by fromdate desc
```

The parameter is then CAST as a date in the query. A bit of a bother really!